# Photoshop saves copyright symbol as UTF-8 (unescaped) in metadata

Tags: php, unicode, encoding, utf-8

**Update - I found this [post](http://www.openphotographyforums.com/forums/showthread.php?p=97681) regarding Photoshop's encoding - saying they "encode the character "©" into Exif metadata in UTF-8 encoding."

** Answer - it was an escaping problem - not an encoding problem. Photoshop allows the copyright symbol in the metadata without escaping it. This is mentioned (and complained about) in the above link. I changed the title to reflect the real issue**

I've read everything on this site trying to save copyright symbol to jpeg metadata. I know the issues are encoding and have tried everything.

Problem:
When I save a copyright symbol to jpeg metadata it shows as `&#xa9;` in Photoshop, but when I load the metadata it comes in correctly.

When writing to the jpeg, I am calling UTF8_to_unicode_array() to encode the string and then unicode_array_to_UTF8() before saving it. Any idea what I am missing?

From UTF8 to unicode:

```
function UTF8_to_unicode_array($utf8_text )
{    
    // Create an array to receive the unicode character numbers output
    $output = array();
    mb_convert_encoding($utf8_text,'utf-8');                
    $atext = mbStringToArray($utf8_text);

// Cycle through the characters in the UTF-8 string
foreach ($atext as $text ){
    $output [] = uniord2($text);
}
return $output;
}

function uniord2($c)

  $ord0 = ord($c{0}); if ($ord0>=0   && $ord0<=127) return $ord0;
  $ord1 = ord($c{1}); if ($ord0>=192 && $ord0<=223) return ($ord0-192)*64 + ($ord1-128); 
  $ord2 = ord($c{2}); if ($ord0>=224 && $ord0<=239) return ($ord0-224)*4096 + ($ord1-128)*64 + ($ord2-128);
  $ord3 = ord($c{3}); if ($ord0>=240 && $ord0<=247) return ($ord0-240)*262144 + ($ord1-128)*4096 + ($ord2-128)*64 + ($ord3-128);
return false;
}


function mbStringToArray ($string) {
  $array = array();
  $strlen = mb_strlen($string);
  while ($strlen) {
    $array[] = mb_substr($string,0,1,"UTF-8");
    $string = mb_substr($string,1,$strlen,"UTF-8");
    $strlen = mb_strlen($string);
}
return $array;
}
```

From unicode to UTF8:

```
function unicode_array_to_UTF8( $unicode_array ){
    // Create a string to receive the UTF-8 output
    $output = "";

    // Cycle through each Unicode character number
    foreach( $unicode_array as $unicode_char )
    {
  $output .= utf8($unicode_char);
}

    // Return resulting UTF-8 String
    return $output;
}

function utf8($num){
  if($num<=0x7F)       return chr($num);        
  if($num<=0x7FF)      return chr(($num>>6)+192).chr(($num&63)+128);
  if($num<=0xFFFF)     return chr(($num>>12)+224).chr((($num>>6)&63)+128).chr(($num&63)+128);
  if($num<=0x1FFFFF)   return chr(($num>>18)+240).chr((($num>>12)&63)+128).chr((($num>>6)&63)+128).chr(($num&63)+128);
return '';
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to find out which encoding the JPEG data uses. If Photoshop doesn't use that encoding, it is buggy and you should claim your money back (and use a free alternative, which is better anyway). If your code needs to handle broken JPEG metadata (e.g. coming from a broken Photoshop), you will have to guess the encoding (maybe Latin-1 or Latin-15) and transcode that accordingly.

Now, assuming you now know the encoding, you can transcode the bytes to UTF-8 (which is a Unicode encoding) for use within PHP. Note that PHP doesn't support Unicode specifically, it still uses byte strings, so anything outside the ASCII range will use more than one character. Keep that in mind when indexing into such a string. The question this also poses is what you mean with "unicode to UTF8", because UTF-8 *is* Unicode.

I know that I'm being a bit optimistic here but it's hard to say in which spot the problem lies. When trying to diagnose this, be sure that you always know the byte values of the string you are dealing with. The reason is that displaying always involves some kind of interpretation, which makes it impossible to tell if displaying or the content was the culprit.

I still have a guess where your problems are though, or at least where you could fix one of them: Your function uniord() will consume a variable amount of bytes from the supplied string. If a single character (like the copyright sign) takes two bytes, you will decode that character and then in the next step decode the second byte of that character again, which just yields garbage. Actually, trying to decode a continuation byte (10xxxxxx in binary) as first byte in a UTF-8 sequence should raise an exception, because that is a sure sign that you don't have valid UTF-8. Do yourself the favour and check for such errors and signal them loudly!

Comment: I've posted a link above which answers the question of Photoshop's encoding: saying it is utf-8. When checking Photoshops Raw Data display of my copyright symbol, it says I am writing `&amp;#xa9;` Any ideas of why the ampersand character appears and what might be missing to have it encode correctly? - Thanks for your help

Comment: The copyright sign has codepoint 0xa9 (10101010 in binary). In UTF-8, you get the bytes 0xc2 0xa9 (Confusingly, second byte equals codepoint!). Another way of encoding is as HTML numeric character reference as string "&#xa9;". If you now replace the ampersand with the according HTML character entity reference in that string, you get the string "&amp;xa9;", so I guess something is double-encoding/escaping the string. However, I also found  openphotographyforums.com/forums/showthread.php?t=11876 which indicates that the EXIF string is ASCII, i.e. doesn't support the copyright sign at all.

Comment: The link you have given gives me all the info I need (to hang myself). If I can't figure it out using this info, so be it. I understand the 2 byte issue, but am new to byte manipulation (especially with php functions). I will check for double encoding/escaping - this may indeed be my issue.

Comment: Unrelated: after a 8+ hours, it seems like adding insult to injury to get down voted (I presume it wasn't you). I've never understood why someone will down vote without constructive feedback. Oh well - I really appreciate your taking the time.

Comment: Thanks for confirming my suspicion it was an escaping problem. I was escaping all characters in the range above 0x7F and so I added an exception for the copyright symbol for the XMP data and still escaping the EXIF and IPTC.

Comment: On second throught, since Photoshop is saving the copyright symbol to the Exif, I will follow suit.